# mail fails to connect to Exchange account

Tags: mail.app, exchange

When I have a poor internet connection, Mac Mail somehow switches into a mode when it no longer can connect to my Exchange email account (no problem with IMAP). In [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/170155/89122) it is suggested that Mail attempts to automatically manage account settings should problems (such as a poor connection) occur, which may it ending up with invalid account settings.

I have now switched this off, but the account is still not working. How can I reset it to the appropriate settings (without deleting and re-instating it – as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272264/89122) – which would re-load ~10000 emails, which I rather avoid)?

I should say that I'm running macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: What do you mean by "poor"?  Is it very slow?  Connection drops?  A combination?

Comment: @Allan this doesn't matter really for the question (it was a public Wifi on a bus). The effect was that Mail no longer access the Exchange account (even from a good connection now). I presume it had changed the account settings, but cannot find a way to re-set them.

Comment: The reason I ask is because Exchange ActiveSync is designed to work with exactly your type of connection.  Apple Mail doesn't support this and uses IMAP.  Apple Mail actually *needs* Exchange Web Services to operate properly. The easiest way to *reset* everything is to delete the account and re-add it because Exchange clients will use an "autodiscover" feature to set all of the server settings.  If you want this to work reliably, switch to Outlook